# TrueCrypt: Whole container broken on single bit error?

Tags: crypt, truecrypt

I wondered what would happen to a TrueCrypt (pre-NSA, i.e. v7.1a) container, if just a single random bit of it gets flipped?
Does this cause the whole container to become corrupted?

Is there a way to fix the container (without knowing which bit was flipped)?

Also: How often does a bit erroneously flip on a common hard drive / flash drive? Does it happen often?